# Issues regarding quadratic equation calculator in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to code a calculator that calculates quadratic equations, but I keep getting a syntax error in the following line:

```
print((int(-b)+math.sqrt(dk))/(2*int(a))
```

Here's the whole code:

```
import math
a=input("Sisestage ruutlige: ")
b=input("Sisestage lineaarliige: ")
c=input("Sisestage vabaliige: ")
dk=((int(b)*2)-4*int(a)*int(c))

if  dk < 0:
    print("Lahendid puuduvad")'


if  dk > 0:
    print((int(-b)-math.sqrt(dk))/(2*int(a))
    print((int(-b)+math.sqrt(dk))/(2*int(a))

if  dk == 0:
    print(int(b)/(2*int(a))
```

Comment: Typo: `((int(-b)+math.sqrt(dk))/(2*int(a))` has one more open-parenthesis than close

Comment: Also, `print("Lahendid puuduvad")'` has a hanging apostrophe. Not sure if that's an error 
 in your actual code or you added it accidentally in the question here.

Comment: Also also: Just convert to `int` when you take the input. It's easier and more efficient than repeatedly calling `int(...)` to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is with your brackets. You're missing a bracket in the print statement.

```py
import math
a=input("Sisestage ruutlige: ")
b=input("Sisestage lineaarliige: ")
c=input("Sisestage vabaliige: ")
dk=((int(b)**2)-4*int(a)*int(c))

if  dk < 0:
    print("Lahendid puuduvad")


if  dk > 0:
    print((int(-b)-math.sqrt(dk))/(2*int(a)))
    print((int(-b)+math.sqrt(dk))/(2*int(a)))

if  dk == 0:
    print(int(-b)/(2*int(a)))
```

While calculating your discriminant, you should use `**` for square instead of the single asterisk. Also, in case the discriminant is zero you're the negative sign.

The rest is fine.

Also, just a suggestion but you can make the input `int` right where you're taking it from the user. That way the code will look cleaner.

```
python

import math
a=int(input("Sisestage ruutlige: "))
b=int(input("Sisestage lineaarliige: "))
c=int(input("Sisestage vabaliige: "))
dk=b**2-4*a*c

if  dk < 0:
    print("Lahendid puuduvad")


if  dk > 0:
    print((-b-math.sqrt(dk))/(2*a))
    print((-b+math.sqrt(dk))/(2*a))

if  dk == 0:
    print(-b/(2*a))
```